# Laravel query-builder for insert data from a external db to another db

Tags: database, laravel, laravel-query-builder

I tried to send data from external db table to internal db table with query-builder in Laravel 5.4v. could you tell me how to modify below code? thanks.

```
DB::connection('ext_db')->table('ext_customers')->chunk(1000, function ($All){
    foreach ($All as $Data){
        DB::connection('inn_db')->table('inn_customers')->insert(
            [
                column1 => $Data->columnToCopy,
                etc..
            ]);
}};
```

Comment: is this code not working ?

Comment: @Vikash Yes. it's not working

Answer (score 1):

I had to do the same thing recently. This is the code I used:

```
$currencies_ext = DB::connection('ext_db')->table('currencies')->get();

foreach ($currencies_ext as $currency_ext) {
    $currency = new Currency;
    // set the values here
    $currency->save();
}
```

If the model you are inserting to is set to use the internal database there's no need to specify a connection for it.

Comment: Excuse me @eric-antoine-scuccimarra . But why in a foreach? How many rows in database will be added this way?